# How to open Facebook app with page share link?

Tags: applications, facebook

I am sharing a page in FB, when the link is opened in mobile it opens the particular page in browser and not in FB app. I want that link to open FB app with the page displayed in it.

Comment: How the link looks (initial characters) and what app you are using to open the link?

Comment: Note for future answerers: **please don't post code**. This site focuses on *end-users* solving their issue, *not developers*.

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure you have installed the latest version of the fb app
2. Make sure fb app is capable of opening the link you are clicking on - may be check on your friends phone to see whether the link opens in the fb app
3. Go to application settings and clear defaults if any for the browser in which the link is opening

--- let me explain in detail the 3rd point
when you click on the link that fb app as well as your browser or any other app could open, you may get a prompt to choose which app you want to use to open the link.

If you choose your browser and tick on remember choice button, the link will then always open in browser.

clearing defaults or uninstalling and installing fb app will help remove this issue.